# Is it possible to invoke ..xyz\jdk1.6\bin\java.exe from a java program which is running on jdk1.5\java.exe?

Tags: java

I am working on a tool which is built using jdk 1.5u22. But, I have to make enhancements, in which I have to use api's which run only on jdk1.6. The project builds but fails while loading jars. I always thought it was jre which loads jars.. How can solve this??

Comment: Please post the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code compiled & ran with JDK 1.5 there's  no reason why it shouldn't run with JDK 1.6 really.

Check the following:

- you're using the exact same compile and run environment when running with either JDK (same classpath, same jars, etc etc)
- make sure you've properlly set CLASSPATH and JAVA_HOME environment variables for either case
- make sure you're actually using the JDK, not the JRE when building/running (in either case). The JDK makes available more APIs and libraries than the JRE, so for example if you were using JDK 1.5 and now you're trying with JRE 1.6 it is possible that it's complaining of missing APIs/libraries

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I was trying to run 1.6 compiled code on jre1.5... I set the paths and it worked..